# python3: speech recognition - calculating features of a WAV file

Tags: python, speech-processing, speech-recognition

I am supposed to do this as a school project, but I am kind of lost when it comes to signals and would appreciate your help. Also, English is not my first language, and I will be translating the assignment mostly literally, as I am not familiar with a lot of terms used in signal processing, so pardon me for any mistranslations, please.

I have WAV files with these characteristics:

- mono
- 16000 Hz
- 16-bit precision
- 16-bit Signed Integer PCM encoding

Right now I am supposed to calculate a vector of features for each frame (sample?) of each WAV file.

They even suggested a solution. They recommended to do this using a *linear filter bank*, which produces 16 coefficients by summing coefficients of a *logarithmic power spectrum*. There's an exact formula, but it's irrelevant for this question, I think.

What can I do to get an array with values of this *logarithmic power spectrum* (is that the right translation)?

I have imported these libraries and can freely use any of its functions: IPython, numpy, matplotlib, soundfile, scipy.signal

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you have a lot to do. I can give you any number of code lines to extract STFT features, mfcc features or other possibilities, though you will not understand what is the meaning of this. I suggest you start reading and watching tutorials and start figure out, what features, what is a sound file, what features are valid for sound and so on. look for a speech recognition tutorial.

Comment: The process is all described in the assignment, I just need the values of the logarithmic power spectrum. I thought I could get it by passing the signal to scipy.signal.periodogram(). It returns an ndarray of "Power spectral density or power spectrum of x", but I tried it and that doesn't seem to be it. It was just a one dimensional field of values. I thought there were supposed to be multiple values for each sample.

Comment: Again, it seems like you are just using trial and error to get a vector\matrix\tensor with similarity to the results you think you are supposed to get. Try and understand what is a power spectrum of x or what is power spectral density. Are they different?  You cant expect to complete a school project by learning nothing. You have to read and learn. Your question (at the moment) is very general because you lack the background.

Answer (score 1):

you can extract most of the well-known features such as **MFCC**, **filter bank**, **PLP**, **Prosodic**, **chroma features** and so on ... using:

1. [speechpy](https://speechpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or [librosa](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/) libraries in **python environment**. You can extract any features from *.wav file. the list of functions is [here](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/feature.html).you can choose the best of them depending on your need.
   for example, you can try for MFCC by [this code](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa-feature-mfcc-1.py). also, it is very easy by [speechpy functions](https://speechpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/features.html#mfcc).
2. Another great tool for feature extracting is **OpenSMILE** by **AudEERING**. You can use it via command line in Windows or terminal in Linux. For more info about it, you can use this [link](https://www.audeering.com/opensmile/). This tool is most cited in speech research papers.